# Creating a website builder with php

Tags: php, mysql, frameworks, web

I have been given the task of creating a website builder that allows people to create websites about their buisness etc. clients are going to be non technical so It should be simple and easy to use, also, I have to maintain the accounts info for all the clients, ie profile, Account details, subscription etc. Im not sure how to go about this. I have mainly worked on php, mysql and a bit drupal, Could some one please suggest me the way forward? I mean is there a php framework or cms I could use? I found a similar question but the difference between this one and mine is the language platform, as my question query relates to php.

Linked:  [Creating a 'website builder' - How would I architect it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059592/creating-a-website-builder-how-would-i-architect-it)

Comment: wordpress multisite installation? http://wordpress.org/support/forum/multisite

Comment: Whats going to distinguish your offering from the competition?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the complexity and requirements the websites would need, I would approach this with a fixed layout that gets populated with database information.

Think of something like this: `mydomain.com/user_website_title`, as the user creates his profile on mydomain.com, a folder is created on the server to accommodate the default files/layouts, you could of course use a framework if you're so inclined. Default database entries are also created for this user, you would display forms via a control panel so that users can change their specific content.

I would first approach this as a single project, create a web application that replicates what  the user would see after filling out the correct information for their website. After that I would consider ways to better implement this server side.